# Highcharts - Highstock: fixed width intervals with scrollbar

Tags: highcharts

I need the points of my chart to have a fixed width (say, 100px each). If the needed space exceed the width of the chart, I just want to be able to scroll horizontally (with the `scrollbar.enabled` parameter set to `true`).

This is the basic setup, without setting the points width:

http://jsfiddle.net/wxxdne19/

If I set the column width like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wxxdne19/1/

The `tickPixelInterval` parameter is ignored (as the [documentation says](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPixelInterval), of course).

I tried a bunch of other things, but none of them worked, and I ran out of ideas. How can I do what I need?

### Update

To clarify what I need, think of it as if I have a column chart, and I need to force all the columns to have a fixed width. Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4rx4snjh/

But, instead of the columns overlapping each other, I'd like the scrollbar to do its job :-) Furthermore, I need it to work with any kind of series (lines, areas...), not just columns.

Comment: check [setExtremes](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis.html#setExtremes) Does this solves issue http://jsfiddle.net/vhnmjaj6/.

Comment: Not really. With setExtremes I should calculate how much 100px "intervals" fit in my chart, and it always would be just an approximation. Isn't really possible to force the width of the points?

Comment: So you want **100px intervals**  in axis

Comment: Correct. I need 100px intervals, and if there are more intervals than fits in the chart's width, the scrollbar should come in.

Comment: Scroll bar will always be there . Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6mrb8mcm/ with `tickPixelInterval`. you can adjust `tickPixelInterval` amount you want

Comment: As I say in the original post, `tickPixelInterval` is ignored if `tickInterval` is set (which I need to do).

Comment: In your example, if you change the tickPixelInterval, you change the interval where an axis' tick is set, not the width of the chart's data. Think of it as if I want to fix the column's width

Comment: Now I can understand what you want. I will try to figure out

Comment: I think together with container width(which will make column width always same), hope  you can achieve you requirements. http://jsfiddle.net/b05179ec/ .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160934/discussion-between-cesar-garcia-tapia-and-deep-3015).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the solution here is to compute extremes manually and set them in `load` event:

```
  load: function() {

    var chart = this,
      xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
      visibleColumns = (xAxis.width - pointWidth) / pointWidth;

    xAxis.setExtremes(pointStart, pointStart + pointInterval * visibleColumns);

  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/mpancrbc/

For some reason (bug probably) `xAxis.min` value must be initialized when the container width is a small value (in my example it's less that 400 px or so).

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes